# Angular Object shows value but cannot get it

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

Ok this may be due to the lack of caffeine or i went brain dead but i cannot seem to figure out how to grab the array of values from this object.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am i missing and if possible why, i want to understand my disconnect from this object vs all my other responses.

Comment: Is it just a lag in the VS Code intellisense?  I have seen that.

Comment: Unless you are using the new HttpClient, the older Http get simply returns an object. It won't know the type and therefore the appropriate set of properties to display. Strongly type your `res` variable or use the HttpClient and strongly type your response.

Comment: I am using httpclient for interceptors to work.

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting the auto completion of intelisense because VS does not know the type it's getting and neither does angular. you can solve this by creating a type for the object you are getting and putting in front of the request `http.get<myType>(...)`

you can access your object with .value and it will return your list regardless if you set a type or not, you just have to know what the keys are without angular/vs telling you.

Comment: did you try restarting vs an recompiling?

Comment: Also getting the value does not exist and wont compile.

Comment: did you try typing it?

Comment: I dont have a class or "model" for it what should i use otherwise ?

Comment: you could export the type for it right above the file if you like just to test it 
`export type myObject: { ... }` otherwise, gonna need more code to figure this out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156104/discussion-between-user1552172-and-fussinhussin).